# Why pip install of a git repository install into the wrong directory?

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, python-3.6

I'm observing a very unpredictable behaviour of pip, I have the following simple requirements.txt file:

```
future >= 0.16.0
git+https://github.com/SamuelDudley/MAVProxy.git@wx_phoenix_wip
git+https://github.com/udacity/udacidrone.git@master
```

when I execute:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

I got the following message:

```
Collecting git+https://github.com/udacity/udacidrone.git@master (from -r requirements.txt (line 8))
  Cloning https://github.com/udacity/udacidrone.git (to master) to /tmp/pip-tf1hz9hg-build
  Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): udacidrone==0.2.0 from git+https://github.com/udacity/udacidrone.git@master in /home/peng/git-drone/__Udacity__/udacidrone (from -r requirements.txt (line 8))
Collecting git+https://github.com/SamuelDudley/MAVProxy.git@wx_phoenix_wip (from -r requirements.txt (line 17))
  Cloning https://github.com/SamuelDudley/MAVProxy.git (to wx_phoenix_wip) to /tmp/pip-j6hsfp8z-build
  Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): MAVProxy==1.6.2 from git+https://github.com/SamuelDudley/MAVProxy.git@wx_phoenix_wip in /opt/conda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 17))
```

It is indicated that only MAVProxy is installed correctly into the python library, which is '/opt/conda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages'

But the project udacidrone is incorrectly installed into '/home/peng/git-drone/**Udacity**/udacidrone'

Why pip is behaving inconsistently? I'm using latest Anaconda 3 environment without virtualenv or pyenv.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: `pip.ini` or `pip.conf` or `PIP_TARGET`?

Comment: Show your syspath: `python -c "import sys; print(sys.path)` and check whether you have a directory named `udacidrone.egg-info/` in `/home/peng/git-drone/Udacity/udacidrone`.

Comment: Having the same problem, how did you solve it?